# Question related to Vector Space

Tags: linear-algebra

A span, of a set of vector, is the smallest vector subspace containing it.  Give example of Vector space, such that the subspace containing the set of vectors, which is greater than span, is infinite infinite in  number.

Comment: *Give example of Vector space, such that the subspace containing the set of vectors, which is greater than span* --- What do you mean by "**the** subspace containing **the** set of vectors"? If someone gives an example of a vector space, there is as yet no specification of a subspace nor a specification of a set of vectors for "**the**" to refer to. Do you mean give an example of a vector space and **an example of a subspace** of that vector space such that the subspace contains **a set of vectors** ... (I'm not sure how to finish to make sense with the rest of what you've said).

Comment: I suppose you mean: "Give an example of a vector space, such that the span of a finite set contains infinitely many elements."? In this case you could look at $\mathbb{R}$ and note that every subspace must contain all scalar multiples of its vectors, since the span itself is a vector space.

Comment: It now occurs to me that "the subspace containing the set of vectors, which is greater than span" could be intended to describe a subspace (your excessive use of commas makes this hard to parse). However, this is still unclear because I don't know what the relation "greater than" pertains to. Linguistically I would guess either "set of vectors" (perhaps subset relation?) or "vectors" (makes no sense mathematically). Also, does "span" refer to this set of vectors? Leaving "span" isolated at the end of the sentence makes the intended meaning difficult to determine.

Comment: If English is not your native language, I suggest you avoid trying to write complex sentences. Instead, state exactly what is assumed or given in short phrases (i.e. $V$ is a vector space; $S$ is a subset of $V$; and so on), and then say what you want to prove. Make it clear where the assumptions end and where the stuff to be proved begins.

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your question? Given a set $X$ of vectors, we always have that $X\subset span(X)$. You can have a countable set of vectors such that the span is uncountable, the $\operatorname{span}({(1,0),(0,1)})=\mathbb{R}^2$ for instance.